# PostGIS is already installed in schema 'public', uninstall it first

Tags: postgresql, installation, postgis-2.0

I am having problems adding postgis to my database.  I'm following the instructions from here: http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#idp32328352  (That said, I have combined some previous instructions from multiple blogs/advices.)

After creating my sample gis db, this is what I'm seeing:

`/c gis
gis=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERROR:  PostGIS is already installed in schema 'public', uninstall it first
gis=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
ERROR:  required extension "postgis" is not installed
gis=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;
ERROR:  required extension "postgis" is not installed`

I think that I may have originally done a `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` on the **postgres** database.  I'm not sure.  I have tried `DROP EXTENSION postgis;` on postgres, but that returns: `ERROR:  extension "postgis" does not exist`.

I have gone so far as to purge postgres and related packages, then reinstalled it.  (Though it seemed to still find the gis db after reinstalling -so I'm not sure it was thorough.)
Am I misunderstanding the message that postgis is installed in schema public?  The sites I have read have advised to install it separately on each gis-enabled DB.

Add'l information: `SELECT version();` Returns: `PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit`

And:  `SELECT postgis_full_version();`  Returns: `POSTGIS="2.1.8 r13780" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN"`
This is a development setup.

Comment: Since you're using PostgreSQL 9.4,4 and Postgis 2.1.8, you may have to drop and create the database again, using only `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`. [Here's](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.5/postgis_installation.html#create_new_db_extensions) more on this.